# What are the relation and difference between a signal mask and a signal set?

Tags: linux, signals

From APUE

> Each process has a **signal mask** that deﬁnes the set of signals currently blocked from
>   delivery to that process.  We can think of this mask as having one bit for each possible
>   signal.  If the bit is on for a given signal, that signal is currently blocked. A process can
>   **examine  and  change  its  current  signal  mask  by  calling sigprocmask**, which  we
>   describe in Section 10.12.
>
> Since  it  is  possible  for  the  number  of  signals  to  exceed  the  number  of  bits  in  an
>   integer, POSIX.1  deﬁnes  a  data  type,  called sigset_t, that  holds  a **signal  set**. The
>   signal  mask,  for  example,  is  stored  in  one  of  these  signal  sets. We  describe  **ﬁve
>   functions that operate on signal sets** in Section 10.11.

What are  the relation and difference between a signal mask and a signal set?

Is a signal mast a datum, and is a signal set an object, as a datum is stored in an object?

What are the differences between, and when shall we use which:

```
#include <signal.h>
int sigaddset(sigset_t *set, int signo);
int sigdelset(sigset_t *set, int signo);
```

and

```
#include <signal.h>
int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *restrict set, sigset_t *restrict oset);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal mask is an attribute of a process, the list of signals that are blocked. `sigprocmask` retrieves and/or updates this attribute of the process.

A signal set is a data type that holds a list of signal numbers. `sigaddset` and `sigdelset` are used to modify an object containing this data.

When you want to set or retrieve the signal mask of a process, the `sigprocmask()` system call takes a parameter whose type is `sigset_t*` to hold a pointer to this list.

It's analogous to the relationship between process IDs and `pid_t`.

So if you want to modify the signal mask of a process, you might do the following:

1. Call `sigprocmask()` with a null `set` and non-null `oset` parameter to get the current process mask in a `sigset_t` variable.
2. Call `sigaddset()` and/or `sigdelset()` to add and delete signals from that variable.
3. Call `sigprocmask()` with `how = SIG_SETMASK` and `set` containing the updated signal set.

If you just want to add or remove signals from the mask, but not both, you can use the `SIG_BLOCK` and `SIG_UNBLOCK` operations to do it in a single call to `sigprocmask`. Just create a signal set containing the signals you want to add or remove, and they'll be merged with the existing mask.

Comment: Thanks. What are the differences between `sigaddset` `sigdelset`  and `sigprocmask`, and when shall we use which.

Comment: Thanks. What kinds of modifications that sigaddset and sigdelset provide?

Comment: The first one adds to a set, the second one deletes from a set. Isn't it clear from the documentation?

Comment: This is like asking what kinds of modifications `+` and `-` provide.

Comment: I've added more details explaining the full process to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that `sigaddset()` and/or `sigdelset()` don't change the signal mask of a process, but only operate on the value of a signal set variable?